# grab multiple lines after a matching line in Perl iteratively?

Tags: perl, hash, pattern-matching

I want a hash structure, each line starting with a **>** is the key and the lines up to the next **>** are the value for that key:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    $line1 = $_;
    chomp($line1);

    if ($line1 =~ /^>/) {
        while (<DATA>) {
            last if $line1 =~ /^>/;
            $value .= $_;
        }
        $hash{$line1} = $value;
    }
}

foreach my $key(%hash) {
    print "$key :$hash{$key}\n";
}

__DATA__
>label1 
line1\n
line2\n
>label2
line1\n
line2\n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash;
my $key;

foreach (<DATA>) {
  chomp; 
  if (/^>(.*)$/) { $key = $1; } 
  else           { $hash{$key} .= $_} 
}

foreach $key(keys %hash) {
  print "$key :$hash{$key}\n";
}

__DATA__
>label1 
line1\n
line2\n
>label2
line1\n
line2\n
```

Answer (score 5):

I think using a key variable with outer scope is the easiest way:

### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $key = 'unlabeled';
my %value;

while (defined(my $line = <DATA>)) {
    chomp $line;

    # key line
    if ($line =~ /^>(.*)/) {
        $key = $1;
        next;
    }

    # value line
    push @{$value{$key}}, $line;
}

say "$_: " . join ', ' => @{$value{$_}} for keys %value;

__DATA__
>label1
line1
line2
>label2
line1
line2
```

### Output

```
label1: line1, line2
label2: line1, line2
```

### Explanation

We save the last seen hash key in the variable `$key` scoped outside the line iteration loop. When the loop sees a next key line, it replaces the `$key` string. If no array for the new key exists, perl's [autovivification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) mechanism creates a new empty array inside the hash. If there's already something in the hash under `$key`, new lines will be added after the existing lines.

**Edit**: if your input doesn't start with a key line, the first non-key lines will be added to the key `unlabeled`.

**Edit 2**: if you want the lines for a label concatenated, this can easily done by `join "\n" => @{$value{$_}}`. If you want it like that *only* you can throw the array stuff away and use @perreal's solution which is very similar but just concatenates new lines.

**Edit 3**: yeah, autovivification! :) (Thanks @TLP)

Comment: You never need to initialize a value with an empty array. Perl's autovivification will handle that for you.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the part. Do you think it's OK like this? Feel free to suggest changes.